# Problem on inequality about $x_1, x_2, x_3, . . ., x_n$ real numbers without using set theory.

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $x_1, x_2, x_3, . . . x_n$ are real numbers between 0 and 1 with sum $s$.  Prove that   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{s+1-x_i} + \prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) \leq 1$$

Is there any method without using set theory to solve this problem?  I tried to prove by induction .

n=1 is true (trivial)
Assume n=k is true and $s= x_1+ x_2+ x_3 . . . +x_k$
Consider n=k+1,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{x_i}{s+x_{k+1}+1-x_i} + \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} (1-x_i)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i}{s+x_{k+1}+1-x_i}+\frac{x_{k+1}}{s+1} + (1-x_{k+1})\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x_i)$$
$$\leq \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i}{s+1-x_i}+\frac{x_{k+1}}{s+1} + \prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x_i)$$
I don't know how to proceed....

Comment: Is it possible to prove it without using set theory?